# Identifying Elements Effectively - AngularJS Automation with Ranorex

Tags: angularjs, testing, bdd, ranorex

I have a relatively big web app is written in AngularJS. Our automation is using Ranorex to run BDD tests.

We are in a constant dilemma on how to enable the Ranorex tests to find UI elements effectively. Currently we're mainly using a custom attribute for it, testid (e.g. `<div testid="done_btn">`), but in some cases it performs very poorly, not sure whether it's because the querying XPaths aren't optimized or some other Ranorex configuration.

Using the `id` attribute is way faster but it just doesn't feel right to use it for automation. Besides, keeping it unique might require some coding in some cases (e.g. when using `ng-repeat`).

Is using `id` just for automation purposes OK or is it a bad practice? Why?

Any way to make Ranorex relate to custom attributes such as `testid` differently so that it'll be found faster? I've read about [Ranorex Weight Rule](http://www.ranorex.com/support/user-guide-20/ranorexpath-weight-rule-library.html) but couldn't find a way to define custom attributes.

Answer (score 2):

The quick answer: YES! Use the Id's.

I'm not actually familiar with the dilemma you are facing. Can you please further explain the reasoning behind not wanting to use the id-s.

And if you face issues related to id's not being unique in some cases you can combine different elements to the path (eg."@id='save_btn' and @innerText='Save'").

Usually if you can improve the speed and stability of your automation with no visual or functional expense - do it.

Comment: generally, we thought that using `id`, which is an attribute with meaning and is part of the HTML specification, just for automation, might not be the best idea, so we preferred using a custom attribute. But as written, this showed bad performance. Thanks :)